# Lighttpd php gets error 500?

Tags: php, iphone, lighttpd

Whenever i try using php with lighttpd on my iphone i get error 500 when loading any php page including the phpinfo.php file.

Comment: Look in the log file to see the detailed error message

Comment: where is the log in the iphone file system, i have ifile. i also have terminal if that will check the log

Comment: lighthttpd should store its errors somewhere, but I don't know where

Comment: i cant find the log, my config file doesn't have logging set up do you know the code i should add?

Comment: Did you install PHP from cydia?

Comment: yes :) i did and this is done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Cydia and install the PHP Hypertext processor package. PHP does not get installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

The location of error log depends on your OS, if you type in console "uname -a" it should tell you what you are using, and depending on that you can Google the exact location of your error log.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have fastcgi working properly? You will get a 500 error if lightppd can't connect to PHP.....

Add this to your config:

fastcgi.debug = 1

And maybe let us see your fastcgi.server settings.

Did you port lighttpd for the iPhone yourself?

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with phppod. Can only help you with generic lighttpd stuff. Try adding more debug flags to the config file: server.errorlog = "/some path/lighttpd_error_log.txt"

debug.log-request-header   = "enable"
debug.log-response-header  = "enable"
debug.log-request-handling = "enable"
debug.log-file-not-found   = "enable"
debug.log-state-handling   = "enable"

Comment: Also can you post your current fastcgi.server setup from the lighttpd config file?